# How to check if trivy is up and running

Tags: docker, security, monitoring, image-scanner, trivy

Trivy scanner documentation does not mention how to test if trivy server is up and running (a simple API call by a monitoring check would be fine in docs).
https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy

```
$ curl http://trivy.local:8080
404 page not found
```

Of course, I could monitor for 404 response, but I would no be sure if trivy is healthy. I would just know it is up.

Answer (score 0):

I found a closed issue https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/issues/534 which mentions using /healthz endpoint:

```
$ curl http://trivy.local:8080/healthz
ok
```

Hopefully, this will help others looking for a simple way to monitor trivy server.